# Hyperplane orthogonal vector (with coordinate system)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

While reading a Linear Algebra book I came across the following claim:

> **Claim**
>
> Let $H$ be an hyperplane $H \equiv a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+\dotsb+a_n x_n+b=0$
>   in a n-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. If the equation is
>   written in an **orthonormal reference system** then its orthogonal unitary
>   vector is $\vec{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1+\dotsb+a_n}}(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$.

I think I understand how it works for Cartesian coordinates (which are specifically orthonormal). I would prove it as follows: let points $c,d \in H \Rightarrow a_1 c_1+a_2 c_2+\dotsb+a_n c_n=-b$ and $a_1 d_1+a_2 d_2+\dotsb+a_n d_n=-b$. Substracting and making $\vec{v}=\vec{cd} \Rightarrow (a_1,\dotsc,a_n)\cdot\vec{v}=0$ ($\forall\vec{v}\in\vec{H}$ since we can choose any $c,d \Rightarrow$ since $\dim H^\bot = n-(n-1),\ <(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)>=\vec{H}^{\bot}$ and we can get the unitary vector dividing with the norm).

However I don't really see how I could prove it for other coordinate systems. Specifically, why does it have to be an orthonormal reference system? Suppose it is not, could anyone give me a counterexample?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Junkai Dong's answer is correct but if someone is looking for something more precise:

Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be our inner product and we have a basis $\beta=\{\vec{a},\vec{b}\}$.

Let $\vec{c}=(c_1,c_2)_\beta,\vec{d}=(d_1,d_2)_\beta\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

We want to know $f(\vec{c},\vec{d}) = f(c_1\vec{a}+c_2\vec{b},d_1\vec{a}+d_2\vec{b}) \stackrel{\text{since f is bilinear}}{=} c_1d_1f(\vec{a},\vec{a}) + c_1d_2f(\vec{a},\vec{b}) + c_2d_1f(\vec{b},\vec{a}) + c_2d_2f(\vec{b},\vec{b})$

Now, if $\beta$ is an orthonormal basis we know that:

- $f(\vec{a},\vec{a}) = 1$
- $f(\vec{a},\vec{b}) \stackrel{\text{inner product is specifically a bilinear simetric form}}{=} f(\vec{b},\vec{a}) = 0$
- $f(\vec{b},\vec{b}) = 1$

So, in this case, we know that $c_1d_1f(\vec{a},\vec{a}) + c_1d_2f(\vec{a},\vec{b}) + c_2d_1f(\vec{b},\vec{a}) + c_2d_2f(\vec{b},\vec{b}) = 1\cdot c_1d_1 + 0\cdot c_1d_2 + 0\cdot c_2d_1 + 1\cdot c_2d_2$.

> So if $\beta$ is an **orthonormal** basis we can claim that:
>   $$f(\vec{c},\vec{d}) = c_1d_1 + c_2d_2$$
>   (otherwise we cannot)
>
> Similarly we can also prove that this is true for all n-dimension $\mathbb{R}$ spaces if $\beta$ is orthonormal:
>
> $$f(\vec{c},\vec{d}) = c_1d_1 +\dotsb+ c_nd_n$$

Going back to my question I claim that $a_1 (c_1-d_1)+\dotsb+a_n (c_n-d_n) = -b-(-b) = 0$.

And (this is the **key**) if our reference system is orthonormal by definition our $\beta$ basis is orthonormal so we can safely write (otherwise not) $0 = a_1 (c_1-d_1)+\dotsb+a_n (c_n-d_n) \stackrel{\beta\text{ orthonormal}}{=} (a_1,\dotsc,a_n)\cdot(c_1-d_1,\dotsc,c_n-d_n)$ (assuming all coeficients are in basis $\beta$).

So, my proof for Cartesian coordinates works for every **orthonormal basis** as well.

Answer (score 1):

It must be an orthonormal reference system, since transforming from one set of orthonormal basis (I would prefer using the name basis) to another preserves the structure of the inner product, and everything else that is deduced from it (distance/length, orthogonality/angle).

If you are confused here is an example. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, with Cartesian basis $e_1=(1,0),\ e_2=(0,1)$. The standard inner product is $e_1\dot\ e_1=1, e_2\dot\ e_2=1,e_1\dot\ e_2=0$ Take the hyperplane(or, a line) $y=0$, and you see that with your argument, the orthonormal vector would be $e_2$. That's good.

However, when you take another basis, such as $f_1=e_1,\ f_2=e_1+e_2=(1,1)$, things change. This time we would have to write our vectors, previously $xe_1+ye_2=(x,y)$ into $x'f_1+y'f_2$. We soon find that $x'=x-y, y'=y$. Again, we look at the line $y=0$, which would be $y'=0$ in the new basis. If we thought (which is what you thought) the orthonormal vector could still be calculated in your way, which would be $f_2$. However, this is not even normal, since $f_2\dot\ f_2=2$. Why? You assumed that in the $f_1, f_2$ basis, the inner product is preserved (which would require $f_1\dot\ f_1=1, f_2\dot\ f_2=1,f_1\dot\ f_2=0$). For linear transformations that preserve the structure, see orthogonal matrices. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does help, upvoted! Let me post my own answer just to explain where my argument would fail to prove the claim (I just realised of it)

Comment: @J.Doe Sure. Good job!